# bluetooth architecture related problem

Tags: bluetooth

can  you tell me in bluetooth can two slaves of the same piconet communicate with each other in the same piconet? if yes then how??

Answer (score 0):

In a Bluetooth piconet of master and slave devices, the slaves communicate only with the master device, not with other slaves.  A piconet is comprised of one master and up to seven slaves, think of a star topology with the master in the center and links spanning out to the slave devices.  Hope this helps.